# Highlighting a Name in Column A if Values in Column C Equal or Exceed an Amount

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm wondering if there is a conditional formatting formula for this particular need.

[image: Chart on Excel]

I want to highlight whoever has been paid over $400. In this example, it would be Nate (70 + 30 + 350 + 50). I'd want his name highlighted (column A) based on if the sum of all instances in Column C that have the same Column A value (that is, all Pay related to Nate) is $400 or more.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Use SUMIFS in a Conditional Formatting rule.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the reply and edit! My understanding of the SUMIFS is that it returns a numerical value based on a sum range/crit range/crit values. It's similar to what I want, but is there a way to return a name (highlight in A) based on a sum of values (sum in C) instead? Thanks!

Comment: Yes your formula refers to column c and the applies to range is column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To highlight who have paid equal or greater use below formula to conditional formatting rule.

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,$A2,$C$2:$C$8)>=400
```

[image]

> If you want to return name then you have to user few other formula in cell not in conditional formatting.